# Multiple Google Chrome Processes

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I open one single page in Google Chrome, it decides to open 5 more processes in the background without my permission.

I have scanned my computer with MalwareBytes, Spybot, and many others but it continues. I have deleted Google Chrome and reinstalled in but this issue remains. It makes by computer very slow. If I attempt to kill the processes using Task Manager,  the other processes pop up again.

How can I stop this?

[image: 2ns screen shot]
[image: Screen shot showing extra google pages open]

Comment: Can you provide details on what pages are popping up? Maybe a screenshot of the tabs or URLs of each extra popup page?

Comment: What i do have is a screen shot that i took from Task Master will that do?

Comment: where / how can I attach the screen shot?

Comment: Have you performed a reset on your browser? Uninstalling and re-installing will not clear user settings, but a reset will purge the nuisance stuff.

Comment: Michael Frank When i try to go to the actual page it doesn't take me there  - like it is hidden

Comment: Michael Frank  - did you get my reply?

Comment: fred_dot_u  I uninstalled and reinstalled and ended up with the same problem

Comment: I currently according to me have one google page open and according to task master I have 10 pages open.

Comment: *I have deleted Google and reinstalled*... If you mean you reinstalled Google Chrome, please say that. Google is not a program.

Comment: I was at lunch. If you are judging the number of tabs based on the processes you can see in Task Manager, and not actual tabs in the browser window, then you are seeing the many processes that run together when Chrome launches. Please read this to find out more: https://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/

Comment: If your question is genuinely about multiple **tabs** opening, then you can add screenshots by [editing your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1475220/edit) and clicking the **Image Icon** from the editing box. If you cannot add images that way, use a website like imgur.com to upload and add the URL to your question.

Comment: Go to settings, and check how many pages are set to open when google chrome opens. Have you tried using another browser?

Comment: Hi Cris  Yes i did same thing happened.

Comment: Michael Frank I have upload 2 screen shots and it seems that you have hit the nail on the head.   I don't recall having this issue before is it normal? if not how can I sort it?

Comment: Hi Delia, I have edited your question to better fit the description based on your clarifications in the comments. If it is incorrect, you can edit it any way you like. As far as the issue you are facing, this is perfectly normal for Chrome and has been for a very long time.